# Getting "Stopped" Hyper-V VM state from PowerShell

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v

I'm using http://pshyperv.codeplex.com/ for managing Hyper-V through PowerShell. 
OS: Windows Server 2012

This PS module can get VMs which are running and, I guess, should get the ones which are in a stopped state. Commands:

Get-VM -Running

Get-VM -Stopped

If getting running machines is no problem and correct list is returned, I have an issue, or maybe lack of knowledge, how to get stopped machines, because when I shut down the machine it is still not returned by Get-VM -Stopped. State of machine is "Off". As soon as I start it, it's on the Running list like nothing happened. VM is NOT deleted completely, just shut down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the native w2k12 hyper-v powershell commands they are much more complete then the codeplex ones.  The ones on codeplex I think are geared to w2k8r2.

Comment: It'd be great if I could use native commands, but I have a closed source external app using codeplex PS commands for controlling HyperV and I can't change that. If this is a incompatibility issue - it is going to be another story then. :)

Comment: ok that does complicate things.

Comment: ok maybe just try the w2k12 powershell script outside of your closed source solution see if it gets the proper response.

Comment: In case two machines are running, one is shut down, Get-VM command from Codeplex PS module returns two machines in state of Running and that's all. Last one is ignored. Of course that is the reason script which is using this call is seeing only two machines, so I was curious if there is some additional configuration needed for Hyper-V in order to see machines in shut down state or, as you said, it is simply incompatibility of codeplex solution with w2k12.

Answer (score 0):

I'll preface this with the fact that I've just started looking at PowerShell and the CodePlex Hyper-V Module today for the first time ever.

That being said I believe the CodePlex Hyper-V module simply has a "bug" in the WQL query used in Get-VM which prevents it from returning VMs which are in the Stopped state (despite what the Get-VM documentation claims).

The problem appears to be the ProcessID part of the where clause. The comment indicates that the ProcessID for a stopped VM should be 0 but that appears not to be the case. The stopped VMs appear to have an ID of NULL. Removing that clause should fix the problem though I don't know what else (other than the Hyper-V host itself) might stop being filtered out at that point.+

I'm assuming that this is a 2K8 -> 2K12 incompatibility rather than assuming that this was always broken but I can't confirm that as I don't have a 2K8 Hyper-V installation to test it on.